# Reuploading files with Python Requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I need to download bunches of images from one site and upload them through a form into another site. I'm using Python Requests for this purpose. Do I just do:

```
r = requests.get(image_url)
requests.post(form_url,files={'f1':r.content})
```

Or do I need to do something with the binary contents of the first response, for it to be understood as a file by the remote server?

Comment: Have you tried? What's the result?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - I understand your sentiment, but I'm afraid that in my case, 'trying' would be too much trouble even than waiting a couple of days to be given such a short bit of code. I'm about to try passing the file through StringIO, that's what Google gave me when I searched about in-memory files.